# How do I share an H2 database over a peer-to-peer network?

Tags: java, database, url, h2

I've been working a bit with H2 over the past couple of days, and I am having some trouble. I run the program on one computer and add some data. Then, I try to run the same program on another computer (even through a shared folder over the peer-to-peer network), and it seems as though the database is stored locally, on each computer.

Now, I have a database set up with the URL `jdbc:h2:C://DatabaseTesting/NewDatabase`. I couldn't get it placed in certain other folders, but I figured this one will do.

Now, if I try to run this program on multiple computers, I can already see what the issue will be. It will create the database on each computer, locally, instead of only on the "server" computer. How can I get all of the computers to link back to the "server" computer for this application?

Comment: In "File" mode, the database will only run in "single user mode" or "single connection mode", this makes it great for applications that want the power of a database for a single user.  H2 also has a server mode.  I suggest having a read through [the documents](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server)

Comment: I read over their documents. Is server mode the only option for connecting to the database in this manner?

Comment: If you want to share the database with more than one user at a time, yes.

Comment: This time, I used `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/NewDatabase`, but it didn't work on any other computer except the computer that I developed the application on.

How do I get the database to be shared via a shared folder over a network?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: 1- Did you run the server process? 2- If you only need a single user to access the database at a time, you should use a variable connection path, so you can configure it.  Allowing multiple computers to connect to the H2 in "file" mode is a really, really bad idea

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really confused with both of your statements. In regards to your first statement, I'm not at all sure what you're referring to. In regards to your second statement, I assume a "variable connection path" is one that can be changed (most likely depending on the computer that is accessing the application), whereas an "absolute connection path" is a concrete file path that will always attempt to link to the same place on every computer. If I am correct, how do I use a "variable connection path"?

Comment: 1- If you want to run database in server mode, H2 comes with an inbuilt server, which you must run (on the PC managing the database), it's covered in the documents. 2- If you want to use a variable path, which could be configured on a machine to machine bases you will need a) a configuration file (maybe a properties file), which can be read by program. b) Change the connection URL to use the value it reads from the file...

Comment: Hmm... Wow... I really don't know much about how to do that stuff... Haha. And, in regards to doing the "inbuilt server", is this something that would allow a user to simply run a JAR file of my application and use it, without having to install and run and edit a bunch of other programs? I am looking for a simple method to access a database in a Java application that any end user could use with simplicity.

Comment: Think about it like this, when you want to browse the internet, do you need to start a web server first?  No, they run on some other computer which you can access (via some wire and a protocol). Same concept.  You start the database server on a central computer and setup the connection URL to point to that computer...

Comment: So, if I set it up on my laptop at home, it would have to constantly be running for the application to work properly on other computers, correct?

Comment: If you want all the other applications to share the same database simultaneously, yes.

Comment: Hmm... So, are there any other database options out there that are integrated into the application and can be accessed from multiple computers? I would just need one computer every time the application is downloaded, to be the server, and the rest of the computers at that specific location can access the data over the network. But is there anything simpler and more straightforward than H2, something that wouldn't involve extra work and extra knowledge on the user end?

Comment: Nope. All database systems pretty much run this way.  The server is acting as the gatekeeper/controller, keeping the database in a consistent state and ensure integrity of the data...

Comment: Okay. So how would I initialize the database on a computer that would act as a server, without the user having to do extra work? Ex: The user of a company downloads my software application, runs it, and can begin adding data to the database immediately.

Comment: You would initialize it once.  It wouldn't matter after that.  So long as the server is running, they should be able to connect to it and use it...If you needed to, you could create new databases like normal...

Comment: Okay, that's great. My company, for example, already requires the "server" computer to be running in order to operate. So, how would I get all of the computers to connect to the databases from one location in a shared network?

Comment: `jdbc:h2:tcp://the_database_server_name_or_ip_address/path/to/your/database`...

Comment: So, when the program starts, I would want to require the user to enter a name (whatever the network is named), and I would want them to enter the computer's user name (because the database files would have to be store in the user folder, or a subdirectory of the user folder), correct?

Comment: I would imagine, that every user would connect to the same database...but yes, you could prompt for the server location...

Comment: Every user WOULD connect to the same database. But the database would be stored on one computer, and it would most likely have to be stored in the user's folder, correct? Ex: \\Ryan\Users\Ryan would be the path for me. (NetworkName\\Users\ComputerUser)? Or is there another way I could do that, so that all I need is the server name?

Comment: Also, it might be easier to allow the user to select from a file browser, rather than typing in the server/network name. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Where the database is stored is up to you, but, if use the path `~/path/to/database` then the database is automatically stored in the current users directory (that's what the `~` is doing, it say "home directory").  An no, you shouldn't allow them to select a file, you kind of end up in the same mess again.  Simply prompt for the database server or have a configuration file from which you can load the value from

Comment: Well, it wouldn't let me do certain file locations. Like C:/Program Files, for example. And I don't know how I would load the value of a network that could be a different name on every computer.

Also, once the user has entered the network name, I would want to save it so that the user could access the database again without having to re-enter the information. How would I store the network name? I couldn't use a database, because I'd be creating a full circle.

Comment: Local config file...see the `Preferences` API or `Properties` as examples...

Comment: ?... Where do I find those?

Comment: The JavaDocs would be a good start, they're built into the standard API

Comment: Okay, so the config file is the only way to do it then, in order to prevent the user from having to enter the network name every time they use the application, correct?

Comment: Or, I guess I could create a couple of text files when the user enters the information, and just access that when the program loads, huh?

Comment: Well, that would still pose a problem. Because, how would the computer know where to look for those files? Ugh... Haha. What a difficult process. I need to know the most simple way to create a database over a network...

Comment: I tried to access it by using the code `java.net.InetAddress inet = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();`. I then used this to get the network and the username, `String network = inet.getHostAddress();` and `String username = inet.getHostName();`. Finally, I tried to access the data by using `"jdbc:h2:tcp://" + network + "/Users/" + username + "/NewDatabase"`. This didn't work... It states that "A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed... Any recommendations? Am I on the right track here?...

Comment: 1- Use a relative path to read the configuration files. 2- It should be simple as something like `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/NewDatabase` The URL will be the same for each computer, the only difference will be the name of the computer you are trying to access

Comment: But localhost will only access the computer that the application is being run on, correct?

Comment: In this case, yes, it's a great way to test the server. Replace local host with actual host name of the server or it's up address

Comment: See, when I put the IP Address in there, that's when I got that last error. Is it because I was trying to access the User folder? If that's the problem, I'm not sure where I could store the database. I'm not sure what the "implicitly relative to the current working directory" error means or why I'm receiving it. A better understanding of this error might help me a bit more.

Comment: It should be been stored in current users directory, that's the point of using ~ at the start of the path. The error seems to be saying that it expects the database to be relative to the current working directory

Comment: But if I store it in the CURRENT user directory, then that would store the database locally on each computer, wouldn't it?

Comment: No. It will be stored in context to the server

Comment: How would it know what the name of the server is?

Comment: You wouldn't, not unless it was stored in a config file, prompted from the user or, you knew in advance, customized to an individual site

Comment: But that would mean I would have to prompt the user every time the program is executed, correct?

Comment: Yes, but you could store the result in config file and present that value back to the user each time so they don't need to type it again

Comment: Hmm... The config file is where I feel like I'm going to have some problems... I'm thinking that it would be easier to just store the database file(s) in the directory that contains the JAR file (most likely the 'dist' folder). Is that possible? And, if so, what would the URL/filepath be?

Comment: Yes, but you're talking about having the database run in standalone mode, it won't be shareable

Comment: If you store the database locally on each machine, it will,not be shareable, it will run i standalone mode. You can't store the local configuration in the database, as you need the database to get the configuration, chicken and the egg. Store the local config in a properties file or within the preferences api. If the config. You are looking for doesn't exist, as the user for it

Comment: I don't know anything about the config file. That's the problem. Would it be easier and better (and possible) to store the database in the same folder that the JAR file is in, the database from it's own directory, no matter where the application contents are stored on the computer? Then, if I create a shortcut to the application on a second computer, it will automatically pull the database information from the computer that the application is actually installed on. Correct?

Comment: But you run into the same problem you started with.  The database will run in single user/standalone mode...

Comment: Why would it run in single user mode? The path to the database would be relative to the location of the application, rather than being stored in a local directory on each machine. Why would it run in single user or standalone mode?

Comment: Because you're not access the database via a server process but directly by the file. H2 will create a lock file which will prevent other processes from accessing the file.

Comment: I thought H2 supported multithreading.

Comment: How would creating a config file that determines what the network is named be any different than putting in a location that could be accessed by every computer without needing to immediately know the name of the server? And, like I said, I thought H2 supported multithreading.

Comment: H2 does support multi threading, but threads are not processes.  So what's the difference in providing a configuration file that does the same thing?  So when you download the program, the config file comes with it?  It's smaller and takes less code to manage.

Comment: You're also not taking into consideration what might happen if the network infrastructure is different between machines and they need to use different host names or IP addresses...

Comment: I think we're making this seem a lot more difficult than it truly is...

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable to me. You want a database system, which can allow multiple, concurrent users to access it - you need a database server stored on centrally accessible computer.  Each client needs to be able to connect to this server. This means they need to provide the server hostname or IP. You can store this in a config file (properties) and have it installed with your application and/or prompt the user for it...

Comment: Hmm... Do you have an idea of any resources that might help me out with this concept? I think I have some research to do.